# Symfony 2/Doctrine: How to lower the num of queries without losing the benefit of ORM?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, twig

I'm using **Symfony 2.7** with **Doctrine**. My controller actions often look like:

```
# my/namespace/Controller/ItemsController.php -> listAction()

$items = $this->get('repository.items')->findAll();
return $this->render('itemsList.html.twig', array('items' => $items));
```

In my templates I like to **iterate associated Entities**:

```
# my/namespace/Resources/views/itemsList.html.twig

{% for item in items %}
    Item: {{ item.name }} <br/>
    Groups: <br/>
    <ul>
    {% for group in item.groups %}
        <li>{{ group.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This causes **many SELECT-queries**, which I'd like to avoid. The only **solution** I know so far is collecting all needed data in a `repository` and assigning it in the `action`, instead of crawling within the template.

I'd like to keep it that way as seen in the twig-snippet. Are there any **smart caching** options that might detect cases like mine and optimize the queries automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried eager loading i.e. `fetch="EAGER"` ?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own repository method, witch joins and selects the groups as well?

Comment: @FuzzyTree `fetch="EAGER"` works for some cases, thanks! I'm trying to use it with caution and prefer my own repository method, supplemented by `fetch="EAGER"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other's have said, you should fetch the group Entities inside your repository. You can use something like this:

```
//inside the repository
public function findAllFetchGroups(){

  return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->addSelect('gs')->join('a.groups', 'gs')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to accomplish your target. You can fetch="EAGER" your related data (but it loads always maybe not necessary data) or use query builder to join related collection, it will be loaded in one query. But remember, to keep code clean - no queries outside repositories :)

Comment: `"no queries outside repositories"` - good rule to share. Thanks!