# Symfony/Doctrine: How to reduce the num of SELECT-queries? (Multi-level associated entities; twig + jsonSerialize())

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, twig

Due to the answer of [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660124/symfony-2-doctrine-how-to-lower-the-num-of-queries-without-losing-the-benefit-o/31668776#31668776) I was able to **reduce the** `SELECT`-**queries** on the first level. Unfortunately the associated Entities are linked deeper, e.g.:

`Item -> Group -> Subscriber -> User ->  username`

**Repository method**:

```
// ItemRepository
public function findAll() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('item')
                ->addSelect('groups')->join('item.groups', 'groups')
                ->getQuery()->getResult()
}
```

**twig template**:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {# Level: 0 #}
    Name: {{ item.name }}<br/>
    Groups:<br/>
    <ul>
        {# Level: 1 #}
        {% for group in item.groups %}
           <li>{{ group.name }}<br/>
               <ol>
               {# Level: 2 #}
               {% for subscriber in group.subscribers %}
                   {# Level: 3 #}
                   <li>{{ subscriber.user.username }}</li>
               {% endfor %}
               </ol>
           </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

**Note**:
I'm using `jsonSerialize` to prepare the JSON-data, which includes multi-level iterating as well.

```
use JsonSerializable;
// ...

class Item implements JsonSerializable {

    // ...

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        $subscribers = array();
        $groups      = $this->getGroups();
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            foreach ($group->getSubscribers() as $subscriber) {
                $subscribers[$subscriber->getId()] = array(
                    'userId'   => $subscriber->getUser()->getId();
                    'username' => $subscriber->getUser()->getUsername();
                );
            }
        }

        return array(
            'id'          => $this->getId(),
            'subscribers' => $subscribers
            // ...
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a way to **join the deeper associated data** as well to **reduce** the number of `SELECT`-**queries** once more *(for twig and jsonSerialize())*?

Comment: Congratulations! You post the 10 000 question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to change fetch mode in the specific query, as described [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql) in the doc.

So you can describe your query as follow:

```
$qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('item')
                ->addSelect('groups')->join('item.groups', 'groups'); // Not necessary anymore

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        // Describe here all the entity and the association name that you want to fetch eager
        $query->setFetchMode("YourBundle\\Entity\\Item", "groups", ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
        $query->setFetchMode("YourBundle\\Entity\\Groups", "subscriber", ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
        $query->setFetchMode("YourBundle\\Entity\\Subscriber", "user", ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER);
        ...

return $qb->->getResult();
```

NB:

> Changing the fetch mode during a query is only possible for one-to-one
>   and many-to-one relations.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for, because I want to avoid `fetch='EAGER'` in my Entity. Note again: `it's not working for many-to-many`!